# Aggregarte with condtions of two df

Tags: r, date, dataframe, aggregate, mean

I am looking for solution that allow me to have the mean of some values in data frame by date depending on two criteria in an other data frame

**Criteria DF**

```
  > dput(Criteria)
structure(list(Name = c("ff", "fd", "fe", "fr", "fz", "fa", "kl", 
"ml", "az", "er", "ff", "fd", "fe", "fr", "fz", "fa", "kl", "ml", 
"az", "er"), Date = c(1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 
 1992, 1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 
 1993, 1993), Value = c("FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", 
 "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", 
 "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", 
 "TRUE")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -20L), .Names = c("Name", "Date", "Value"))
```

**Return DF**

```
> dput(Return)
structure(list(`Names ` = c("ff", "fd", "fe", "fr", "fz", "fa", 
"kl", "ml", "az", "er", "ff", "fd", "fe", "fr", "fz", "fa", "kl", 
"ml", "az", "er", "ff", "fd", "fe", "fr", "fz", "fa", "kl", "ml", 
"az", "er"), Date = structure(c(8065, 8065, 8065, 8065, 8065, 
8065, 8065, 8065, 8065, 8065, 8186, 8186, 8186, 8186, 8186, 8186, 
8186, 8186, 8186, 8186, 8490, 8490, 8490, 8490, 8490, 8490, 8490, 
8431, 8431, 8431), class = "Date"), Value = c(0.2, 0.43, NA, 
0.52, -0.002, NA, 0.001, NA, 0.22, 0.32, 0, 0.001, 0.032, 0.9123, 
1, 0.32, 0.43, 0.0312, 0.0312, 0.43, 0.53, 0.84, 0.001, -0.0123, 
0.43, 0.134, 0.74, 0.0312, 0.9324, 0.06)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), .Names = c("Names ", "Date", "Value"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried to calculate the mean Value of **Return DF** per date , but this mean value should be calculated just for companies have the condition TRUE in **Criteria DF** in that Year

my solution was

```
 for (val in Return$Value) {
 if (year(Return$Date)%in% year(Criteria$Date) & Criteria$Value == TRUE)
 result = aggregate(Return$Value, by=list(Return$Date), mean, na.rm= TRUE)
 }
 print result
```

But I failed using the `aggregate` function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
x <- Criteria[Criteria$Value==TRUE,]
ag <- aggregate(Value~Names+Date, Return, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
y <- data.frame(Name=ag$Names, 
       Date=format(as.Date(ag$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y"),"%Y"), Date1=ag$Date, Mean=ag$Value)

merge(x, y, by = c("Name", "Date"))[,c("Name", "Date1", "Mean")]
```

So you first do aggregation based on full data (i.e., variable `ag`) and then filter out the result based on the Name and Year in other data frame (by doing merge).

```
 # Name      Date1   Mean
# 1   az 1992-05-31 0.0312
# 2   az 1992-01-31 0.2200
# 3   er 1993-01-31 0.0600
# 4   fd 1992-01-31 0.4300
# 5   fd 1992-05-31 0.0010
# 6   fe 1993-03-31 0.0010
# 7   kl 1992-01-31 0.0010
# 8   kl 1992-05-31 0.4300
# 9   kl 1993-03-31 0.7400
```

Comment: Clever Try 989, Just I want to have the monthly mean of the True companies summerised in one value for each month with the same work you did it, the out put will be c("Date","Mean")

Answer (score 1):

Consider formatting Return's *Date* to Year format, then run merge / subset / aggregate. Try also renaming fields to avoid duplicate names requiring suffixes after merging: *.1*, *.x*, *.y*:

```
Return$Year <- format(Return$Date, "%Y")

mdf <- subset(merge(Criteria, Return, by.x="Date", by.y="Year"), Value.x==TRUE)

aggdf <- aggregate(Value.y~Date.1, mdf, FUN=mean)

#       Date.1   Value.y
# 1 1992-01-31 0.2412857
# 2 1992-05-31 0.3187700
# 3 1993-01-31 0.3412000
# 4 1993-03-31 0.3803857
```

[R fiddle for demonstration](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=ztQWinMd&version=1)

Even consider a dense one-liner:

```
aggdf <- aggregate(Value.y~Date.1, 
                   subset(merge(Criteria, 
                                transform(Return, Year = format(Date, "%Y")),
                          by.x="Date", by.y="Year"), Value.x==TRUE), 
                   FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Thank you (Parfait), It was very helpful for me.

Comment: Parfait, there is an other solution instead of subset(merge , cause when I applyed on my real data which is a bigdata I have an  Error # Error in merge.data.frame(BH, RI_melt, by.x = "Year", by.y = "Year") : 
  cannot allocate vector of length 1447721280 #